# Note combination doesn’t sound right on digital piano

Tags: sound, digital-piano

So I’m trying to learn this song, but I have a bit of a problem. The left hand part from 00:00 to 00:08 sounds weird and not correct on my digital piano. I don’t know how to explain it, but it just sounds weird and out of tune. Could it possibly be me who needs to practice some more or is it the piano? I’m a beginner and I’m using a SDP-2 stage piano by Gear4Music.

Here’s the video:

Comment: Maybe this video can help? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=khrF7J_YmUw

Answer (score 1):

We have 4 bars of Gmaj7, then 4 of F#min7.   In both chords, the 7th of the chord (F#, then E) appears both in the LH accompaniment and as the melody.  The F#, beiong a major 7th, is quite an astringent sound, the E, a minor 7th rather less so.

I don't think this would sound any different on another piano or with another player.  It's just a rather brash musical effect.  We could be rude and call it a crude one.  But I think it's what the composer intended.

Answer (score 1):

You are playing the correct notes at a suitable tempo, but your interpretation is not sensitive yet. **The problem is the dynamics.** The major sevenths should produce a nostalgic, longing effect, and that cannot be achieved if you play them the same straightforward way as a consonant chord in a march.

The five opening notes are supposed to be quiet and wistful, almost like a whisper coming from silence, but they are currently loud and even. The right-hand melody is fine, and the bass notes are gently prominent; but **the repeated notes in the left hand should be much softer, not much more than a murmur, and even the melody should be only *mp*.** Other than that your performance is nice.

It *might* be easier to achieve a full variety of dynamic levels on a real piano, but this model has weighted keys and adjustable touch, and in any case one hears insensitive performances on expensive real pianos all the time.

**Your digital piano has by default a very piercing, "bright" sound which could exaggerate dissonances.** You may want to adjust the treble response; look at your manual for information about EQ adjustment. If you are having trouble playing *pp*, you should also adjust the touch settings.